# Check that two fields belong to the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have several models:

- User = an ordinary user class (does not belong to anything)
- Challenge = any sort of competition (does not belong to anything)
- Team = a list of users (belongs to Challenge)
- Coach = name and role of a coach, which can be shared between several teams, but exists only for a given Challenge (belongs to Challenge)
- TeamCoach = an association between Team and Coach (belongs to Team and Coach)

I want to make sure that it is impossible to have a TeamCoach with a Team and a Coach that do not belong to the same Challenge.

My current (working) implementation is the following:

```
class TeamCoach < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :coach_id, :team_id

  belongs_to :coach
  belongs_to :team

  validates :coach_id, :presence => true,
                       :uniqueness => { :scope => :team_id }

  class SameChallengeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
   def validate(team_coach)
     if team_coach.team.challenge_id != team_coach.coach.challenge_id
       team_coach.errors[:base] << "The team and coach do not belong to the same challenge."
     end
   end
  end 

  validates_with SameChallengeValidator
end
```

**Is there a shorter, more elegant way to do the SameChallengeValidator validation?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to write your own validator class.  You can just use the [validate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate) method instead:

```
class TeamCoach < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :coach_id, :team_id

  belongs_to :coach
  belongs_to :team

  validates :coach_id, :presence => true,
                       :uniqueness => { :scope => :team_id }
  validate :team_and_coach_belong_to_same_challenge

  private
   def team_and_coach_belong_to_same_challenge
     errors.add(:base, "The team and coach do not belong to the same challenge.") if self.team.challenge_id != self.coach.challenge_id
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It is indeed shorter.

Small detail: I think you forgot to copy-paste the `if team_coach.team.challenge_id != team_coach.coach.challenge_id` and `end` lines, which are the ones I would like to have automatically written for me every time I have to do this kind of validation :)

Comment: No, they are there :)  Scroll to the right.  In Ruby, you don't need to always structure the `if` blocks the way you did.  Instead, you can put them *after* a method to keep it all one line.

Comment: My bad, scrollbars aren't displayed on OS X Lion so I missed it! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help!  If this answers your question sufficiently, please do me a favor and hit the checkmark next to my answer to close the question.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will wait a little more to see if someone has an answer without using any custom validator. I was hoping the validates method could handle such cases. If that really doesn't exist, I will accept your answer :)